# How to remove KDevelop 5 on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kdevelop

I have downloaded KDevelop 5 from https://www.kdevelop.org/download

```
wget -O KDevelop.AppImage 
http://download.kde.org/stable/kdevelop/5.0.3/bin/linux/KDevelop-5.0.3-x86_64.AppImage
chmod +x KDevelop.AppImage
./KDevelop.AppImage
```

Now, I want to remove it, how can i do that? Thank you.

Comment: Why did you install it bypassing the software management system you have? You made a "wild installation", now you have to clean it up manually too.

Comment: I wanted to test it, a now i want delete it. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, but since you have no information about what has been done during that installation you will have to dig yourself what files have to be deleted...

Comment: @arkascha: Installing KDevelop via the AppImage is supported by the KDevelop team, it's an easy way to get the most recent version of KDevelop without tinkering with distro software repositories, etc. pp.. It's simply a standalone file which can be removed easily (e.g. it's not an installer)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @kfunk It might well be that that form of installation is "supported by the KDevelop team", but what difference does that make? That form of installation still bypasses the systems software management and prevents you from taking benefit of it's features and advantages. You are thrown back to the insecure and flaky way software is installed on MS-Windows systems: you find some file in the internet and hope best you can by the file name that it contains what you want. And you are on your own to handle it. Why not build a clean package for the system instead? With all the advantages in that?

Comment: @arkascha: Citing the AppImage author: "As an application author, I want to provide packages for Linux desktop systems, without the need to get it 'into' a distribution and without having to build for gazillions of different distributions." -- it's as easy as that. For some applications it makes sense to provide up-to-date packages so users can start testing/using it right away.

Comment: Also note: This is off-topic. The user just wanted to know how to clean up afterwards, this problem is solved.

Comment: @kfunk Many people have a motivation for what they do. Does that automatically mean it is good what they do? Certainly _not_. Wild installations cause many problems, just as we could see in this thread. Why should one follow such an advice? Let's be honest: the reason why people offer such "installer" packages is to not have to deal with the simple process of creating a valid package. That's all.

Comment: @arkascha Note KDevelop *is* packaged on a wide range of distros, it's just not possible to install the *latest* version easily. That's what the AppImage is for. If you think that packaging a software like KDevelop (with several dependencies that need to be kept in sync) for the sprouting market of Linux distros out there is an easy task, then, well, sorry, I cannot help you. :)

Comment: @kfunc No further comment.

Comment: @kfunk Although... why not... I myself packaged kdevelop over some 4 years whilst I used it myself. I had absolutely no issue doing that for 3 different distros at that time back in my company. Why do people always think that creating a package for an existing software is voodoo, especially if there are already build recipes for it. So stop muttering excuses. If you want to go the dirty way, sure, go. But please don't tell others that is a great idea. Thanks.

Comment: For your interest: https://www.linuxcounter.net/statistics/distributions (there's more than 3 distros)

Comment: @kfunk I am neither the creator of kdevelop, nor am I claiming that I want to take over that job. Other software producers are able to provide packages for all mainstream distributions too. It is not as if you have to do that yourself, there are things like build services these days. And upgrading a package along with its dependencies usually just means to take the package build sources, upgrade them and keep the existing recipes, maybe adjusting them here or there a bit. And it is not as if a new kdevelop version with completely changed dependencies is released every two days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The KDevelop AppImage is just a standalone executable.

In order to remove it you can simply remove the downloaded file:

`rm KDevelop.AppImage`

Comment: We've updated the download page now, with better instructions how to remove KDevelop again: https://www.kdevelop.org/download -- Thanks!